# jQuery tabs: good plugins for ie7 site?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, tabs

Im going to make a page with a 2 level tab system. Ive always been using jQuery UI tabs, and they work ok in ie7 i guess. But i would like to know if there are any options worth mentioning in terms of jquery plugins. My only requirement is that they work in ie7. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the jQuery UI and combine it with the Cookie Plugin to restore the Active Tabs after Reloading and some other Situations.

But there are some good others like the Tabs Plugin from jQuery Tools.